Will my S3 bucket delete the objects in a versioned bucket?
I have a large bucket which I just added a lifecycle rule to that will expire the object after 90 days. There is already a lifecycle rule in place that will remove noncurrent versions past (the newest) 5, after 365 days. My question is that many folders have versioning enabled, yet only 1 file of that object is present. I see that it added a delete marker to these objects, but am curious if those old versions will end up getting deleted.
Will every 90 days a new delete marker be added, until eventually there are more than 5 noncurrent versions. Which, when the file reaches a year, it will be actually deleted?
Or is the file going to sit around under the delete marker indefinitely, until I add a new rule or change the noncurrent versioning rule?
I added the lifecycle rule, which expires objects after 90 days. I am waiting to see if that will eventually delete the versioned object. But would like a definitive answer instead of waiting 450 days.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

You can create a custom lifecycle rule !
You can help you with this documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-rule.html
For example :
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: GlacierRule
            Prefix: glacier
            Status: Enabled
            ExpirationInDays: 450
            Transitions:
              - TransitionInDays: 1
                StorageClass: GLACIER
Outputs:
  BucketName:
    Value: !Ref S3Bucket
    Description: Name of the sample Amazon S3 bucket with a lifecycle configuration.

